# Unable to run a PowerAutomate Flow on a SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, power-automate, json-formatting

I am unable to run a Power Automate flow within my created SharePoint list.

The code which I used seems to be ok, however when I click on the button within SharePoint and try and run my flow I get the following error:

[image]

What is more I attach the code which I used for generating my SharePoint button(for "Start The Automate" Column).

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"669e6a08-ca95-431f-829b-19232c541a32\"}"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "background-color": "transparent",
    "cursor": "pointer"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Flow"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "6px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "Start the Automate"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Then name of the flow makes me believe that the flow is not a "user triggered" flow but rather one that triggers automatically when you add items to the list, hence you cannot start it manually like you try to do

Comment: Oh, ok I see your point. So you are basically trying to say that in order to run a flow I would need create a flow without a trigger at the beginning? I have actually tried that with another flow(which is not user triggered) and I was still unable to launch my flow from SharePoint

Comment: I will suggest you to use the **[For a selected item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#for-a-selected-item)** trigger from SharePoint connector.

Comment: Great!!! Thanks a lot @GaneshSanap this has solved my problem completely. Now when I try to run my flow it is completely executable. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to run a Power automate flow from SharePoint list using JSON formatting,

I will suggest you to use the **For a selected item** trigger from SharePoint connector to run the flow instead of "When an item is created" trigger.

Check below documentation for this trigger: [For a selected item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#for-a-selected-item)

**Additional Reference**: [Create a button to launch a Flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-advanced#create-a-button-to-launch-a-flow)